# Як найкраще перекласти ідіому "second to none"?

Tags: from-english, переклад, фразеологізми, сленг

Ідіома *second to none* [означає](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/second+to+none) *better than everything else*, тобто *чудовий, найкращий*. Проте так само можна перекласти і *awesome*, і *wonderful*. Відомо,що ідіоми створюються для підсилення ефекту, тому виникає питання, чи є якісь відмінності чи особливості вживання цього виразу з точки зору спілкування з іноземцями?

Варто зазначити, що згідно вікісловника [second to none](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/second_to_none) виступає у ролі сленгового прізвиська наркотичної речовини героїн.

---

Idioma *second to none* [means](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/second+to+none) *better than everything else*. I guess that *awesome* and *wonderful* are also good alternatives for saying something is the best. Indeed, idioms are used for the enhancing effect so the question is any conditions or rules where we should use *awesome* or *second to none* with native speakers?

Note that according to wikitionary [second to none](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/second_to_none) is an alias for drug heroin.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Цим висловом скористався Шекспір у своїй «Комедії помилок»: *«Second to none that lives here in the city»*. У перекладі Ірини Стешенко це звучало так: *«Нема в Ефесі рівного йому»*. Зміст цієї ідіомі можна передати словом **незрівнянний** або ж **неперевершений**.

Серед висловів такий зміст має **«ні з чим/ким незрівнянний»** і подібні до нього, а також **«кращого не знайти»**. Тож там, де це доречно, можна перекладати висловом. Якщо не лізе — просто прикметником.

Comment: Хороша відповідь. ІМХО, це дуже правильно — звернутися спочатку до наявних перекладів творів, де оригінальна фраза вживається.

Answer (score 8):

Ще є варіанти:

- «**[не мати собі рівного](http://sum.in.ua/s/maty)**»;
- «**не знати собі рівних**» <sub>(щодо вживаності та 100%-ї правильності не впевнений, але, здається, чув в дитинстві в перекладі серіалу «Повітряний вовк» на ICTV)</sub>.

Comment: Я розглядав різні приклади вживання, коли готував свою відповідь. Цей варіант можна додати до загальної купи, і мені він подобається також. Якщо контекст дозволятиме, то можна. +1!

Answer (score 6):

Не знаю щодо найкращого перекладу, але "second to none" дослівно означає - якщо "цей об'єкт" поставити на друге місце, на перше місце не знайдеш що поставити (з чого зрозуміло що кращого просто немає).

Тобто **кращого не знайдеш** або **кращого не знайти.**

Comment: гарне пояснення оригінальної фрази

Answer (score 2):

Я б сказав *неперевершений, неперевершена, неперевершене, неперевершені*

I would use *неперевершений, неперевершена, неперевершене, неперевершені*

Answer (score 2):

Знайшов ще один [варіант](http://translate.academic.ru/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0/ru/en/1) перекладу:

**перший сорт**

Answer (score 1):

Аналітичний переклад: *нічого кращого*.

Якби було *second to X*, то перекладалось би *кращий тільки Х*.